# Trying to get width for apex:pageBlock

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout

I have a long title in my apex:pageBlock

```
<apex:pageBlock title="I have a very very very very very long title here and it wraps">
```

and it wraps to the next line.  I try adjusting width

```
<apex:pageBlock title="I have a very very very very very long title here and it wraps" style="width:600px">
```

But it still wraps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your VF page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pbTitle {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You try overriding the header facet. Something along the lines of:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:facet name="header">I have a very very very very very long title here and it wraps</apex:facet>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

You should be able to wrap your statement in a div or something and then properly style it.